# How to import a file as a module while passing parameters into the main code

Tags: python, module, parameter-passing, program-entry-point, python-module

I'm struggling with this small problem, I'm sure it has a simple solution but cannot find it.

I have one file called test1.py, and another called test2.py

My code for test1.py:

```
import test2(*Variable name*)
print(test2.add(1, 2))
```

My code for test2.py:

```
c = *Variable name*

def add(a, b):
    sum = a + b + c
    return sum
```

I want to be able to pass in a parameter, when importing test2.py into test1.py, which will be put into the main section of the code within test2.py

This is a simplified version of my problem and the variable c needs to be declared in the main code.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a class:

```py
# test2.py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c

    def add(self, a, b):
        sum = a + b + self.c
        return sum
```

In your test1 you simply import the Module, Instantiate a class, passing c into the constructor:

```py
from test2 import Test 
t = Test(5)
print(t.add(1,2)) # = 8
```